# Why write Try-With-Resources without Catch or Finally?

Tags: java, try-with-resources

Why write Try without a Catch or Finally as in the following example?

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet tryse</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet tryse at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }

}
```

Comment: read about try with resources (Java 7)

Comment: See [Try with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Duplicate of "Does it make sense to do “try-finally” without “catch”?"

Comment: @Juru: This is in no way a duplicate of that...

Comment: Having said that, I don't imagine this is the first question on try-with-resources.  Nevertheless, +1 simply because I'd never heard of this feature before!

Comment: Correct, my bad I was too fast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is try-with-resources catch block selectively optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497053/why-is-try-with-resources-catch-block-selectively-optional)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

As explained above this is a feature in Java 7 and beyond. `try with resources` allows to skip writing the `finally` and closes all the resources being used in `try-block` itself. As stated in [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

> Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.

See this code example

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

In this example the resource is `BufferReader` object as the class implements the interface `java.lang.AutoCloseable` and it will be closed whether the try block executes successfully or not which means that you won't have to write `br.close()` explicitly.

**Another important thing to notice here** is that if you are writing the `finally` block yourself and both your `try` and `finally` block throw exception then the exception from `try` block is supressed.

While on the other hand if you are using `try-with-resources` statement and exception is thrown by both `try` block and `try-with-resources` statement then in this case the exception from `try-with-resources` statement is suppressed.

As the @Aaron has answered already above I just tried to explain you. Hope it helps.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: So it's analogous to C#'s using & IDisposable 's.

Comment: @roufamatic yes, analogous, though the large difference is that C#'s `using` does not protect in any way against exceptions, it just guarantees resource closure at the end of the block. In C#, you most often have to combine `using` blocks with `try` blocks. Java's `try-with-resources` does this together.

Comment: If an exception is thrown from both the `try-with-resources` statement and the `try-with-resources` block, only the `try-with-resources` statement exception would be encountered (would not be suppressed) because the `try-with-resources` block wouldn't have an opportunity to execute.

Answer (score 13):

This is a new feature in Java 7 and beyond. Without this, you'd need a `finally` block which closes the resource `PrintWriter out`. So the code above is equivalent to:

```
PrintWriter out = null;
try {
    PrintWriter out = ...
} finally {
    if(null != out) {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {} // silently ignore!
    }
}
```

See [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: They are not equivalent. If the exception throws from both try and finally blocks, the exception from try block will be suppressed with try-and-catch. On the other hand, if you use the try-with-resources statement, the exception from finally block (auto close throws exception) will be suppressed.

Comment: @Nier Fixed the finally part.